# how to set selected option in asp.net mvc using knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, selectlistitem

I'm trying to set an option selected by default based on value recieved from Model.
I'm using asp.net mvc and knockout js for data binding.

**//Model.TestValue="DEF"**

**script section.**

```
<script>
var model = {
            MyData: ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model)))
        };

ko.applyBindings(model);  
</script>
```

**View Section: Razor**

```
@{
   var mydropdownlist = new SelectList(
        new List<SelectListItem>
        {
new SelectListItem {Text = "ABC", Value = "1"},
new SelectListItem {Text = "DEF", Value = "3"},
new SelectListItem {Text = "GHI", Value = "5"}
        }, "Value", "Text");

}
```

**View Section HTML.**

```
<select data-bind="options: mydropdownlist, optionsText:'text', value:MyData.testValue "></select>
```

Now **mydropdownlist** is populationg fine but I couldn't set "DEF" selected by default.

Comment: ko is case sensitive, use `Model.TestValue` not MyData.testValue

Comment: tried that as well. but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Set the observable property MyData.testValue, with the required option reference from the mydropdownlist.

MyData.testValue(mydropdownlist.Items()[1]); //DEF

Example:

$(function() {

```
    var VmClass = function() {
        self.MyOptions = ko.observableArray([
            { Name: 'Jhon', Age: 45 }, { Name: "Peter", Age: 67 }, { Name: 'Oliver', Age: 90}
        ]);

        self.SelectedOption = ko.observable();

        // can select after binding initialized as well.
        self.ClickMeToSelect = function() {
            self.SelectedOption(self.MyOptions()[2]);
        };
        self.ClickMeToSelect();
    };

    var vmInstance = new VmClass();
    ko.applyBindings(vmInstance, document.getElementById('[element-id]')); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```js
var data = [
  {"text": "ABC","value": 1},
  {"text": "DEF","value": 2},
  {"text": "GHI","value": 3},
  {"text": "JKL","value": 4},
];

var model = {
  mydropdownlist: ko.observableArray(data),
  selectedOption: ko.observable(data[1])
};

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="options: mydropdownlist, optionsText:'text', value:selectedOption "></select>

<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root.selectedOption)"> </pre>
```